# Error: File ended while scanning the use of \beamer@modeinline

Tags: beamer, errors

Using the following code, I consistently get an error stating:
File ended the use of \beamer@modeinline.

Additionally, the console output contains the following: 
Runaway argument?
{\par \par \begin {document} \par \par \begin {frame} \begin {i\ETC.
! File ended the use of \beamer@modeinline.

Any help is greatly appreciated! MWE:

```
    \documentclass{beamer}
    \mode<presentation> {


    \usepackage{graphicx} 
    \usepackage{booktabs} 
    \usepackage{beamerthemesplit}
    \setbeamertemplate{footline}[frame number]

\begin{document}


\begin{frame}
\begin{itemize}
\item The usual necessary conditions for an optimum:
\begin{align}
$F_{K}(K_{t}^{d}$,$L_{t}^{d})&=r_{t}$\\
$F_{L}(K_{t}^{d}$,$L_{t}^{d})&=w_{t}$
\end{align}

\item[-] (These two equations do not determine $K_{t}^{d}$ and $L_{t}^{d}$ 
 from given $r_{t}$ and $w_{t}$; they only determine $\dfrac{{K_{t}^{d}}
 {L_{t}^{d}}}$
\item In equilibrium:
\begin{itemize} 
\item The marginal product of capital equal the rental price of capital.
\item The marginal product of labor equals the wage.
\end{itemize}
\begin{itemize}
\item (Note that $ F_{K}(K_{t}$,$L_{t}$) represents the first derivative of 
 the production function w.r.t. capital).
\end{itemize}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Did you try finding the errors yourself? E.g., in the second line, you have an opening bracket, but there is no matching closing bracket. You have several similar errors (e.g., begin statements of environments without corresponding end statement). If you can't find an error, try commenting out parts of the code until the error disappears in order to know where the issue is.

Comment: @magula Of course! Yes, I was wondering about that second line closing bracket as the template I am using does not close that bracket and it has not affected other presentations in which I use this template's preamble. Hence, I assumed it was an issue. I do not see the other statements with missing corresponding end statements. Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 2):

As [magula](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/394215/error-file-ended-while-scanning-the-use-of-beamermodeinline/394217#comment979949_394215) mentioned in his/her comment, there are several errors.

- Missing `}` in the preamble
- the `align` environment is already in math mode
- you open more `itemize` environments then you close
- random distribution of brackets (have a look at `$ F_{K}(K_{t}$,$L_{t}$)` -- should the `()` be inside or outside of the math environment? Why do you close and reopen it anyway?)
- no need for `graphicx` with beamer
- not a `tex` problem, but in your text you open a `(` which you never close ...

---

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\mode<presentation> {

    %\usepackage{graphicx} 
    \usepackage{booktabs} 
    \usepackage{beamerthemesplit}
    \setbeamertemplate{footline}[frame number]

}

\begin{document}


\begin{frame}
    \begin{itemize}
        \item The usual necessary conditions for an optimum:
        \begin{align}
            F_{K}(K_{t}^{d},L_{t}^{d})&=r_{t}\\
            F_{L}(K_{t}^{d},L_{t}^{d})&=w_{t}
        \end{align}
        \item[-] (These two equations do not determine $K_{t}^{d}$ and $L_{t}^{d}$ from given $r_{t}$ and $w_{t}$; they only determine $\dfrac{K_{t}^{d}}{L_{t}^{d}}$
        \item In equilibrium:
        \begin{itemize} 
            \item The marginal product of capital equal the rental price of capital.
            \item The marginal product of labor equals the wage.
        \end{itemize}
%\begin{itemize}
        \item (Note that $F_{K}(K_{t},L_{t}$) represents the first derivative of the production function w.r.t. capital).
    \end{itemize}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you for your help! That solved the problem and I will be sure to look over your suggestions and changes to make sure this sort of problem does not occur again.
Quick follow up question: So align automatically puts the environment into mathematical mode?